# Esprimo pri "The Burn"

Tags: single-word-requests

Mi serĉas la terminon por la sento de brulado en la muskoloj, kiam oni faras intensa fizika ekzersado.

En la angla: *the burn*

En la franca: *brûlure musculaire*

Guglo proponas "brulvundo", sed tio ne povas esti ĝusta. Tiu esprimo temas pri fajrovundo. En Tekstaro, ĉiuj esprimoj kun "brulvundo" temas pri fajro.

Eble:

- "muskola brulvundo": sed mi ne parolas pri vundo
- "muskola brulo": sed mi ne parolas pri fajrobrulo
- "muskolbrulo": sed mi neniam vidi tiun ĉi esprimon

Viaj pensoj estus plej aprezitaj.

Comment: Mi ne intense fizike ekzercas min, do mi ne scias, kion signifas "la senton de brulado en la muskoloj". Ĉu temas pri "bruligi grason" aŭ alia metabola reakcio? Vi certe ricevos pli bonajn respondojn, se vi precizigos vian demandon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

muskola brulsento, (tio estas, sento de brulo, ne vera brulado!)

Answer (score 1):

Temas pri muskolŝiretoj kaj la termino estas false pozitiva, kvazaŭ io bona. En la germana (mi pensas) *Muskelkater* (postebrio, *hangover*). Do speco de *inflamsento*. inflamo = [brulumo](https://reta-vortaro.de/revo/dlg/index-2b.html#brul.0umo). Do **muskolbrulumo** eblus.